# Is an ObjectId automatically generated for a nested object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My schema is as follows:

```
const MessageType = {
   // ...
   oAuth: { provider: String, id: String },
   attachments: [ {name: String, contentType: String} ],
   // ...
}
MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(MessageType, { timestamps: true});
Messages = mongoose.model("Message", MessageSchema);
```

When I insert a new Message document using `Messages.create`, an `ObjectId` (`_id`) is also generated for `attachments`, in addition to my `name` and `contentType` fields, ie:

```
[ { name: "xxx", contentType: "yyy", _id: zzzzzz }]
```

Why is this happening, for `attachments` but not `oAuth`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For avoiding that the _id was generated you must set the option **_id: false**, Also if you don't want to save the empty attachments object, you need to set **default: undefined**.

```
const MessageTypeSchema = new  mongoose.Schema({
    oAuth: {
        type: String
    },
    attachments: {
        type: [
            {
                type: String
            }
        ],
        _id: false,
        default: undefined
    }
});
```

Here the code that I used to test:

```
 console.log('-------- Document with attachments --------');
    new MessageTypeModel({
        oAuth:'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        attachments: ['teste.png','teste2.jpg']
    }).save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });

    console.log('-------- Document without attachments --------');
    new MessageTypeModel({
        oAuth:'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }).save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

And here the result of execution:

[image: test execution]

Mongoose creates _id for **single nested subdocuments** or **arrays**, and your object field **oAuth** is not one of this cases:

> Subdocuments are documents embedded in other documents. In Mongoose,
>   this means you can nest schemas in other schemas. Mongoose has two
>   distinct notions of subdocuments: arrays of subdocuments and single
>   nested subdocuments.
>
> Each subdocument has an _id by default. Mongoose
>   document arrays have a special id method for searching a document
>   array to find a document with a given _id.

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  // Single nested subdocuments. Caveat: single nested subdocs only work
  // in mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

Link of Mongoose documentation: [Mongoose SubDocs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Comment: My question was why does it generate `_id` for `attachments` but not `oAuth`?  The `_id` was in the `attachments` object, in addition to one in the main document.

Comment: I updated my answer with this information, it happens because the mongoose consider array a Subdocument and String not, and for all Subdocuments mongoose will create a _id by default. Documentation Link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: @OldGeezer, I understood your question, mongoose will only generate _id for  **Single nested subdocuments** e.g. field {child: childSchema}  or **arrays** {attachments: [type:String]}, your object field **oAuth** is not one of this cases. Documentation Link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: Isn't my `oAuth` a single-nested subdocument? Each element of `attachments` has the same shape as `oAuth`.

Comment: @OldGeezer your **OAuth** is not another schema inside MessageTypeSchema(that is way it is not a **single-nested-subdocument**, but attachments is a **array**, and _ids will be generated by default for **arrays** or **single nested subdocument(nested schema)**, I added a example code and link in the end of the my answer.

Comment: Can you omit the `_id: false` in your code sample and see the result. The documentation is talking about arrays of subdocuments, and not simply arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `_id : false` in attachments array.

```
const MessageType = {
   // ...
   attachments: [ {name: String, contentType: String, _id: false} ],
   // ...
}
```